# Parameter estimation in bivariate linear models

Tags: regression, estimators, multivariate-regression

I'd like to simulate data from a bivariate normal distribution to a regression problem. In other words, let $X = (X_1, X_2)$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two matrices $n \times 1$. $X_1\sim N(3, 2)$ and $X_2 \sim U[0, 2]$ with unknown parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta_1} = \boldsymbol{\beta_2} = 1.5$. And let $Y$ be the dependent variable ($n \times 2$) such as its vector of mean is $\boldsymbol{\mu} = (\boldsymbol{\mu_1}, \boldsymbol{\mu_2})^T$, where $\mu_1 = X_1 \boldsymbol{\beta}_1$ and $\mu_1 =  g(X_2\boldsymbol{\beta}_2)$ (consider $g(\cdot)$ identity). I builded the dependent variable as $Y_i \sim N_2(\mu_i, \Phi)$ for $\Phi = I$ (identity, firstly).

Considering $Y = (Y_1, Y_2)^T$. Why are my estimators for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ always close to zero when  I make $(X_1^TX_1)^{-1}X_1^TY_1$ and $(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^TY_2$?

Comment: Writing is mess. For example:  "X1 and X2 be two matrices n×p. X1∼N(3,2)" X1 is matrix or just a number?

Comment: Sorry, they are $n \times 1$ vectors.

Comment: Still mess: "unknown parameters β1=β2=1.5"